# maven error while running sonar from jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-2

I am  trying to implement Sonar in Jenkins CI using maven build tool.I am using Linux machine to build maven with Sonar.
maven is successfully installed. I have tried  to configure maven path in Jenkins Configuration, 
maven is installed .
whenever I run the job getting below error.

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory 
\"/directorypath"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory""

as I understood from error that its unable to find out maven in Job directory. what configuration should needed so job can take by default maven path where is installed.

I have searched lot on internet, but could not helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try without mvn in the commands

Eg clean install package

Comment: Could You pls more brief

Comment: I found the solution..it was maven installation issue..I have installed maven 3.2.2.now its working fine